# Find Text, Insert Rows then Copy & Paste after changing specific Text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data of rows and columns and I would like my macro to find certain text (Location) in one column and upon finding the location create 2 or more rows and copy the data of the found Location row but change the Location by an increment of 1.  For example if it finds a value in Location Column London then copy the whole row to the 2 new inserted rows but change the London text with London1 and London 2 and so on.  Please help.

**code**

```
sub Insert_CopyPaste()

    Dim LastRow As Long 
    With Sheets("Sheet2") 
        .Activate 
        LastRow = .Range("C6000").End(xlUp).Row 
        For i = 2 To LastRow 
            If (InStr(1, .Range("c" & i).Value, "03M-EX", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then 
                .Range("a" & i).EntireRow.Copy 
                .Range("a" & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert 
                .Range("a" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
            End If 
        Next
    End With 
    Exit Sub 

End Sub
```

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: A good starter tip for making macros to do such things.  Turn on the Record feature and do the steps by hand.  Then review the code it creates.  It will not be perfect, but will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is what you're after. If it's not clear I can explain.

```
sub Insert_CopyPaste()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i as long, txt as string
    txt = "03M-EX" 'set text to search
    With Sheets("Sheet2") 

        LastRow = .Range("C6000").End(xlUp).Row  
        while i <= lastrow 

            If .Range("c" & i).Value = txt Then 

                .Range("a" & i).EntireRow.Copy 
                .Range("a" & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert 
                .Range("a" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
                .Range("c" & i + 1).value = txt & "1" 'add 1 to text

                i = i + 1 'skip newly added row
                lastrow = lastrow + 2 'increase last row reference by 2

                .Range("a" & i).EntireRow.Copy 
                .Range("a" & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert 
                .Range("a" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesxlPasteValues 
                .Range("c" & i + 1).value = txt & "2"

            End If 

            i = i + 1 'goto next row to check 

        loop
    End With  
End Sub
```